# Org-Mode and Yasnippet with <backtab>

Tags: emacs, org-mode, yasnippet

In Emacs, how can I modify the org-mode keymap so that shift-tab runs yas-expand instead of org-shifttab? Better yet, how can I make it so that shift-tab only runs yas-expand when point is in front of a snippet trigger, and runs org-shifttab otherwise?

Also, I saw this entry in the org-mode wiki. The first option didn't work, and I couldn't get the second option working as I could not find the `backtab` equivalent of `org-tab-first-hook`

> The way Org mode binds the  key (binding to [tab] instead of
>   "\t") overrules YASnippet's access to this key. The following code
>   fixed this problem:
>
> ```
> (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
>           (lambda ()
>             (org-set-local 'yas/trigger-key [tab])
>             (define-key yas/keymap [tab] 'yas/next-field-or-maybe-expand)))
> ```
>
> The latest version of yasnippet doesn't play well with Org mode. If
>   the above code does not fix the conflict, start by defining the
>   following function:
>
> ```
>       (defun yas/org-very-safe-expand ()
>         (let ((yas/fallback-behavior 'return-nil)) (yas/expand)))
> ```
>
> Then, tell Org mode what to do with the new function:
>
> ```
>       (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
>                 (lambda ()
>                   (make-variable-buffer-local 'yas/trigger-key)
>                   (setq yas/trigger-key [tab])
>                   (add-to-list 'org-tab-first-hook 'yas/org-very-safe-expand)
>                   (define-key yas/keymap [tab] 'yas/next-field)))
> ```

Comment: Not answering your question, but I've solved the TAB issue by using SPC for YASnippet operations (like in TextMate, BTW IIRC).

Comment: If you're interested, you can take a look at my config on GitHub (https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven/blob/master/emacs-leuven.el).

Comment: Ideally I'd be able to keep backtab as the trigger key..

Comment: The easiest way to disable org-mode-map bindings is to define the same key with that map as `nil` -- e.g., `(define-key org-mode-map [(shift tab)] nil)`  Here is a link to an example where I set various mappings to `nil`:  http://superuser.com/a/828744/206164